# How To Use MySQL Value From Previous SELECT

Tags: mysql

I want to have SQL command like this :

```
SELECT ID, SenderNumber, TextDecoded,
(SELECT DISTINCT A.Username, A.ProspectCellPhone, B.CellPhone, A.WebsiteURL
FROM Prospects A 
INNER JOIN User B ON A.Username = B.Username
WHERE A.ProspectCellPhone = '*****') AS NumSite
FROM inbox 
WHERE Processed = 'false'
```

the problem is the part ***** is actually SenderNumber from previous SELECT. How to use the value of SenderNumber from previous SELECT into SELECT DISTINCT.

thanks.

Comment: how are the three tables related with each other?

Comment: Looks like you will be getting an error on your sub query (sub query return more than 1 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're referring like this query:

```
SELECT ID, SenderNumber, TextDecoded,
(SELECT DISTINCT A.Username, A.ProspectCellPhone, B.CellPhone, A.WebsiteURL
FROM Prospects A 
INNER JOIN User B ON A.Username = B.Username
WHERE A.ProspectCellPhone = inbox.SenderNumber
) AS NumSite
FROM inbox 
WHERE Processed = 'false'
```

This may be return an error (sub query return more than 1 rows) but if you can give more details about your question, that would be better so I can correct my answer.